# how to create reusable state in react hooks?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, react-hooks

I have 5 buttons in my app which I would like to change the background color based on button states, so now when I click one button it affects all the buttons, these buttons are used to copy something in UI, each one copies something different.

**Note: I know I can create five states for each button and everything will be fine but I think this is a bad solution.**

**Also, assume each but have its own icon and text, we should be able onclick button to change the text to `COPIED` and change the icon of the button too**

Like this here.

[image]

Here is what I have so far

```
    import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
    
    function Mata() {
    const [isCopied, setIsCopied] = useState(0);
    
    
        return (
            <div className="container">
                <button style={{ backgroundColor: isCopied ? '#262626' : '#F3F3F3'}} className={`btn1 ${isCopied && activeTab}`} onClick={handleBtn1}>Copy anything</button>
                <button style={{ backgroundColor: isCopied ? '#262626' : '#F3F3F3'}} className={`btn2 ${isCopied && activeTab}`} onClick={handleBtn2}>Copy something</button>
                <button style={{ backgroundColor: isCopied ? '#262626' : '#F3F3F3'}} className={`btn3 ${isCopied && activeTab}`} onClick={handleBtn3}>Copy Imgae</button>
                <button style={{ backgroundColor: isCopied ? '#262626' : '#F3F3F3'}} className={`btn4 ${isCopied && activeTab}`} onClick={handleBtn4}>Copy text</button>
                <button style={{ backgroundColor: isCopied ? '#262626' : '#F3F3F3'}} className={`btn5 ${isCopied && activeTab}`} onClick={handleBtn5}>Copy Link</button>
             
            </div>
        )
    }
    
    export default Mata
```

How can I create just one state eg `const[isCopied, setIsCopied] = useState()`; and use it in any button related to copying something in UI?

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps create your own React Component which encapsulates your idea, and use that component.

Here is a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/morning-cloud-pnrzv?file=/src/App.js) showing how it can be customized to fit your needs, as well as passing a function for the onClick event for each button.

Below a simple snippet.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ColouredButton title="Copy something" />
      <ColouredButton title="Copy something" />
      <ColouredButton title="Copy Imgae" />
      <ColouredButton title="Copy text" />
      <ColouredButton title="Copy Link" />
    </div>
  );
}

const ColouredButton = props => {
  const [isCopied, setIsCopied] = useState(0);
  return (
    <button
      style={{ backgroundColor: isCopied ? "#262626" : "#F3F3F3" }}
      className={`btn1 ${isCopied && activeTab}`}
      onClick={() => setIsCopied(prevState => !prevState)}
    >
      {props.title}
    </button>
  );
};
```

Comment: very good solution my brother, Gandzal assume onclick each of these button u need to change the text  and icon as here https://ibb.co/m9b0brz , how can we acomplish that with your solution?

Answer (score 1):

Probably three separate answers here:

### I'd just use file `useState` calls

Since you've said the handlers are all separate, and you're writing the buttons separately, I'd just use five `useState` calls. Simple, clear, avoids cross-talk between the buttons.

But you've said you don't want to do that, so on to answer #2... :-)

### Use an array of handlers and an object for the flags

(Actually, I don't like this one as much as the following one; so read it, but then keep reading.)

You could put those functions in an array and probably make the flags an object keyed by the `id` of the button, which we can create from the index:

```
function Mata() {
    const [isCopied, setIsCopied] = useState({});

    // ...create handlers...

    const buttonHandlers = [handleBtn1, handleBtn2, handleBtn3, handleBtn4, handleBtn5];

    return (
        <div className="container">
            {buttonHandlers.map((handleBtn, index) => {
                const flag = isCopied[index];
                return <button id={index} style={{ backgroundColor: flag ? '#262626' : '#F3F3F3'}} className={`btn${index+1} ${flag && activeTab}`} onClick={handleBtn}>Copy anything</button>;
            })}
        </div>
    );
}
```

Within the handler function:

```
function handleBtn1(evt) {
    // ...logic...
    if (/*...need to set the flag...*/) {
        setIsCopied(isCopied => ({...isCopied, [evt.target.id]: true}));
    } else if (/*...need to clear the flag...*/) {
        setIsCopied(isCopied => ({...isCopied, [evt.target.id]: true}));
    }
}
```

Someone may tell you that `id` values can't start with digits. That's incorrect, they can. It's CSS ID selectors that can't start with an unescaped digit, but we're not using CSS here.

### Use an object for the flags keyed by the `id` of the button

Or do away with the array entirely as it's not buying you much anymore:

```
function Mata() {
    const [isCopied, setIsCopied] = useState({});

    // ...create handlers...

    return (
        <div className="container">
            <button id="btn1" style={{ backgroundColor: isCopied.btn1 ? '#262626' : '#F3F3F3'}} className={`btn1 ${isCopied.btn1 && activeTab}`} onClick={handleBtn1}>Copy anything</button>
            <button id="btn2" style={{ backgroundColor: isCopied.btn2 ? '#262626' : '#F3F3F3'}} className={`btn2 ${isCopied.btn2 && activeTab}`} onClick={handleBtn2}>Copy something</button>
            <button id="btn3" style={{ backgroundColor: isCopied.btn3 ? '#262626' : '#F3F3F3'}} className={`btn3 ${isCopied.btn3 && activeTab}`} onClick={handleBtn3}>Copy Imgae</button>
            <button id="btn4" style={{ backgroundColor: isCopied.btn4 ? '#262626' : '#F3F3F3'}} className={`btn4 ${isCopied.btn4 && activeTab}`} onClick={handleBtn4}>Copy text</button>
            <button id="btn5" style={{ backgroundColor: isCopied.btn5 ? '#262626' : '#F3F3F3'}} className={`btn5 ${isCopied.btn5 && activeTab}`} onClick={handleBtn5}>Copy Link</button>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: looks awesome solution but one question I have five functions which are responsible for each button action, as I wrote that every button is doing something else, so how do I pass each function here in `handlebtn` ? through switch?

Comment: @TheDeadMan - Are the functions defined within the `Mata` component, or elsewhere?

Comment: within the mata component

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try `useReducer()` hook for that.

If you have experience using redux before, you can understand easily on the concept.

You can read more about useReducer hook here.

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer

Comment: I am looking so far for simplified solution which I can Understand quickly thanks though